# запуск копии проекта на Django для python3

Tags: python, django

Долго времени суток комрады. Дело в том что, жёсткий диск посыпался. Пришлось восстанавливать проект с помощью софта для восстановления данных. Добыл я директорию с проектом виртуалкой и статическими файлами тобишь полность весь проект. Далее я установил ubuntu 16.04, python3.6, pip, postgresql, virtualenv, django и все что нужно было, скопировал все папки и файло сохранив старые пути, создал бд и пользователя с старыми данными. Запускаю virtualenv все ок, но когда делаю миграции или запускаю сервер python3 manage.py runserver выпадает стек ошибок, единственное статические файлы нормально переносятся. Я так понимаю нужно создать проект через django-admin startproject xxx, а потом переносить код из старого в новый?

```
(myprojectenv) test@dhcppc91:~$ cd ~/project
(myprojectenv) test@dhcppc91:~/project$ python3 manage.py runserver 192.168.1.191:8000
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f57bbe3fc80>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 379, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 366, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 396, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 533, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 526, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/test/project/analytics/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from www_analytics import views
  File "/home/test/project/www_analytics/views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleapiclient'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 379, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 366, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 396, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 533, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 526, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/test/project/analytics/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from www_analytics import views
  File "/home/test/project/www_analytics/views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleapiclient'
(myprojectenv) test@dhcppc91:~/project$ source /home/test/project/myprojectenv/bin/activate
(myprojectenv) test@dhcppc91:~/project$ python3 manage.py runserver 192.168.1.191:8000
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f31d383cc80>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 379, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 366, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 396, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 533, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 526, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/test/project/analytics/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from www_analytics import views
  File "/home/test/project/www_analytics/views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleapiclient'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 379, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 366, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 396, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 533, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 526, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/test/project/analytics/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from www_analytics import views
  File "/home/test/project/www_analytics/views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleapiclient'
```

Comment: Для начала надо разобраться, что эти ошибки значат-то. Вдруг после startproject будут те же самые ошибки?

Comment: Полный текст ошибки добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: Добавил ошибки. Да пытался понять но т.к. с джанго опыта только набираюсь разобратся не могу, что это значит.

Comment: Все гут.Мне надо быть внимательней в следующий раз. Дело бы в том что я не правильно указал имя администратора БД и не установил компонент гугл апи который использую в своем проекте. Тоесть нужно было установить все библиотеки которые используем, чтобы пути в ОС прописались, иначе пайтон не видит их, ну и записывать все на листочек чтобы потом не перепутать. Всем спасибо.

Comment: Записывать библиотеки надо было в общепринятый файл requirements.txt

Comment: Да да что и сделал сейчас.